# How to get Solana transaction data from transaction object

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, solana-transaction-instruction

I'm doing a simple transaction with a single `transfer` instruction for 0,1 SOL from one account to another. Then I want to get the transaction data and use it to verify the data it carries - in this case that a transfer has been made for 0,1 SOL.

I use [getTransaction](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getTransaction) with the tx signature and get a response like this:

```
{
  message: Message {
    header: {
      numReadonlySignedAccounts: 0,
      numReadonlyUnsignedAccounts: 1,
      numRequiredSignatures: 1
    },
    accountKeys: [ [PublicKey], [PublicKey], [PublicKey] ],
    recentBlockhash: '9S44wiNxXZSdP5VTG6nvaumUJBiUW1DGUXmhVfuhwTMh',
    instructions: [ [Object] ],
    indexToProgramIds: Map(1) { 2 => [PublicKey] }
  },
  signatures: [
    '8ykRq1XtgrtymXVkVhsWjaDrid5FkKzRPJrarzJX9a6EArbEUYMrst6vVC6TydDRG4sagSciK6pP5Lw9ZDnt3RD'
  ]
}
```

So, I dig into `message.instructions` and find the following object:

```
{ accounts: [ 0, 1 ], data: '3Bxs411Dtc7pkFQj', programIdIndex: 2 }
```

Ok, so `data` is the `base58`-encoded string `'3Bxs411Dtc7pkFQj'`. I decode that from base58 (using [bs58](https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/bs58)), but that only gives me a Uint8Array, which I am not really sure how to convert into a JS object.

I can see in [the tx in Solscan](https://solscan.io/tx/8ykRq1XtgrtymXVkVhsWjaDrid5FkKzRPJrarzJX9a6EArbEUYMrst6vVC6TydDRG4sagSciK6pP5Lw9ZDnt3RD?cluster=devnet) that the `data` information is decoded into `hex`:

[image]

And I can also get this info in my script:

```
---> Instructions:
{ accounts: [ 0, 1 ], data: '3Bxs411Dtc7pkFQj', programIdIndex: 2 }

---> Instructions Data:
3Bxs411Dtc7pkFQj
0200000000e1f50500000000
-----
```

But not sure what to do next. How do I get the actual `amount` data out of it.

So, I guess the question is: How to decode the instruction data into a JS object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was redirected to solana.stackexchange.com and there I found [the answer](https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/624/1010). Basically, I could use `getParsedTransaction` instead of just `getTransaction`.

The parsed function would give me exactly what I need, since the `instructions` prop is an array containing one object (in my case), which looks like this:

```
{
  parsed: {
    info: {
      destination: 'foo',
      lamports: 100000000,
      source: 'bar'
    },
    type: 'transfer'
  },
  // ... other props
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, for your second question:

To know how to deserialize the array returned from the bs58 decoding you need to know how the sender serialized the instruction.